# ArrayStoreException during array byte concatenation

Tags: java

Below is my code to convert a string into its ascii equivalent. The string will contain only numbers - which is why I am allocating 2 byte for each character (since 1 to 9 is 49 to 58 in ascii respectively)
But I am getting a java.lang.ArrayStoreException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method) . Any idea why this is happening? Keep in mind that I will be only putting in numbers as Strings as mentioned before.

```
public byte[] intToAscii(String assetId) { // class main


int stringLength = assetId.length(); 
byte[] retBuf = new byte[stringLength];
int offset = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < stringLength ; i++){                
    char character = assetId.charAt(i); 
    byte ascii = (byte) character; 
    System.arraycopy(ascii, 0, retBuf, offset, 1);
    offset += 1;
    }
return retBuf;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and third parameter to [`arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) must be arrays, and `ascii` is a `byte`, not a `byte[]`.

If you want to convert the string `assetId` to ASCII bytes, just call [`getBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.nio.charset.Charset%29):

```
public byte[] intToAscii(String assetId) {
    return assetId.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII); // or getBytes("US-ASCII") if pre-Java 7
}
```